# famo.us click really slow respond sometimes multiple clicks get ignored, has anyone faced this?

Tags: famo.us

I am not sure what the state of click is with the new version 0.3.0 but even with fastclick. On click event handlers are really slow to respond. Sometimes the first few clicks are just ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastclick seems to ignore taps that the browser perceives to be a touchmove. See pull request for the needed changes for this to work https://github.com/Famous/famous/pull/421